# Why is a collection of <enum> unable to cast to an <int?>?

Tags: c#, linq, casting

Why is a collection of `enum` unable to cast to an `int?`

```
enum Test { A = 1, B = 2 };

int? x = (int?)Test.A; // Valid

var collection1 = new[] { Test.A }.Cast<int>().ToList();

// InvalidCastException has thrown (Specified cast is not valid.)    
var collection2 = new[] { Test.A }.Cast<int?>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Cast` method can only perform boxing/unboxing conversions, reference conversions, and conversions between an enum type and its underlying integral type. The unboxing has to be to the right type though - it can't unbox to a nullable type (unlike the C# conversion).

```
var collection1 = new[] { Test.A }.Cast<int>()
                                  .Select(x => (int?) x)
                                  .ToList();
```

For each value, the `Cast` will unbox from the boxed `enum` value to the `int` value, and then the `Select` will convert the `int` value to an `int?` value.

In this case you can *also* get away with this:

```
var collection1 = new[] { Test.A }.Select(x => (int?) x)
                                  .ToList();
```

i.e. no `Cast` step. However, that *doesn't* work if you have an `object` array instead:

```
// Fails
var collection1 = new object[] { Test.A }.Select(x => (int?) x)
                                         .ToList();
```

You can't unbox a boxed enum value to a nullable int value. The `Cast` version still works in that case, however, as it splits the two steps (unboxing first to `int`, then converting from `int` to `int?`.)

Comment: Interesting. I don't remember ever casting using linq that way, I only use known types `:/`... I suppose `{ Test.A }.Select(x => (int?)x).ToList()` should work as well?

Comment: @Kobi: See my latest edit - I've gone through a few versions :)

Comment: One could also avoid the `Cast<>()` by casting the value twice in the select: `Select(x => (int?)(int)x)`. However, the `Cast<>()` is needed if the collection implements only non-generic IEnumerable.

Comment: @mgronber: Yes both counts :)

Comment: Note: it is very simple to make it work with object collections using the conditional operator `?:`.

Answer (score 3):

It is because internally `Cast()` does something like:

```
object o = Test.A;

int i = (int)o; // This is valid.
int? ni = (int?)o; // This is not valid!
```

You would have to first `Cast()` to an int:

```
var collection3 = new[] { Test.A }.Cast<int>().ToList().Cast<int?>().ToList();
```

or not use `Cast()` at all:

```
var collection4 = new object[] { Test.A, null }.Select(i => i == null ? null : (int?)(int)i).ToList();
```

Comment: @mgronber: I have noticed. That's why I fixed it 3 minutes ago.

Comment: @Jaroslav: Do you know why `Cast<int>().Cast<int?>()` doesn't work ?

Comment: @Homam: Internally the `Cast<>()` does box the value to object before casting it to target type and you cannot cast boxed enum directly to `Nullable<>` type. It works internally just like Jaroslav has shown. The `Cast<int?>()` for `Test.A` is same as `(int?)(object)Test.A` and it will always fail.

Comment: Still, it is interesting that `Cast<int>().Cast<int?>()` does not work, because `Cast<int>().Select(x => x).Cast<int?>()` works fine.

Comment: @Homam, mgronber: simply put the first enumerator just passes the `object` to the next enumerator. `int? ni = (int?)Test.A;` works only because of optimisations - the compiler will turn it into: `int? ni = 1;`, also `int? ni = (int?)testA;` will end-up as `int? ni = new int?((int)testA);`.

Comment: Of course. The first `Cast<int>()` returns `object` because it is used through `IEnumerable` interface and so it ends up to be a no-op.

Comment: Uh, it still does not make any sense. The `Test` is cast to `int` before it is get through `IEnumerable` so the second cast should be simple `(int?)(object)2` and that should work.

Comment: @mgronber: The `Cast()` does not wrap an enumerator, if it's already the correct type. `Cast<int>()` has no effect on the enumerator instance. It is in this case the same as `new[] { Test.A } as IEnumerable<int>`. `arr.Cast<int>().Cast<int?>` is therefore the same as `arr.Cast<int?>()` and since `IEnumerator.MoveNext()` casts the value to `object` first, it throws.

Comment: @Jaroslav: Ok, now I finally understand this. So it is a no-op if `((IEnumerable)new[] { Test.A }) as IEnumerable<int>` is not null. Thank you very much for your patience :)

Comment: @Homam see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292623/castint-castint-applied-on-generic-enum-collection-results-in-invalid-cast and the followup question to it..

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't work because we need to understand what is enum and what is int? (nullable int)

**int?** is not really an int it is a generic instance of Nullable, - The syntax T? is shorthand for System.Nullable, where T is a value type. The two forms are interchangeable. [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28VS.80%29.aspx)

**Enum** The default underlying type of the enumeration elements is int.[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Therefore an implicit conversion between int and enum exists. But implicit conversion between an enum(int) to Nullable (which is entirely different reference type) doesnt exist. That is why you see an InvalidCastException exception.

Where as in the first `int? x = (int?)Test.A;` statement you are forcing the explicit conversion to either box the value type and get an integer or get a null, which is works because boxing an enum into `object` then unboxing it as `int?` is returning an int.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why `Cast<>()` does not work but you can use `Select()` to do what you want.

```
var collection = new[] { Test.A }.Select(item => (int?)item).ToList();
```