# Cast<int>.Cast<int?> applied on generic enum collection results in invalid cast exception

Tags: c#, casting, enums, type-conversion

```
enum Gender { Male, Female }

var k = new[] { Gender.Male }.Cast<int>().ToList().Cast<int?>().ToList(); //alright

var p = new[] { Gender.Male }.Cast<int>().Cast<int?>().ToList(); //InvalidCastException
```

What is the cause for the second case? I know I cant cast a boxed `enum` to `int?` directly, but I do a two stage casting, ie `Cast<int>.Cast<int?>` which should be working.

**Edit:**

This is surprising considering the below works:

```
object o = Gender.Male;
int i = (int)o; // so here the cast is not to an entirely different type, which works
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I have come to find out the cause, which is still strange. I should have checked up `Cast<T>` implementation myself first of all!

This is how `Cast<T>` is implemented:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
{
    IEnumerable<TResult> enumerable = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;
    if (enumerable != null)
    {
        return enumerable; // this is the culprit..
    }
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    return Enumerable.CastIterator<TResult>(source);
}

private static IEnumerable<TResult> CastIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source)
{
    foreach (object current in source)
    {
        yield return (TResult)((object)current);
    }
    yield break;
}
```

Now the problem is with the **first** `Cast<int>` call:

```
new[] { Gender.Male }.Cast<int>()
```

Here `source as IEnumerable<TResult>` where `source` is `new[] { Gender.Male }` and `TResult` is `int` **in the generic method** returns a non null value (which basically means (`new[] { Gender.Male }` is an `IEnumerable<int>` in generic context), and hence it returns the same enumerable back which is `Gender[]`, and in the next `Cast<int?>` call, the actual cast is performed, which is from `Gender` to `int?` which fails. As to why this happens in generic context, [catch it in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292988/enum-is-ienumerableint-returns-true-in-a-generic-method?lq=1).

Comment: This still leaves questions... It won't fail *if* the Extension method took `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable`. The exception comes from the `yield return` line, where it tries to cast a *boxed* instance of `Gender` to `int?`. You can easily write `MyCast<TIn, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TIn> e)` and `MyCastIterator<TIn, TResult>(IEnumerable<T> e)` and it will work because it won't box it. Why does casting a boxed enum type to an `int?` fail, but casting a boxed `int` to an `int?` succeeds, and a non-boxed enum type to and `int?` also succeeds *even though* it says (***object***)current?

Comment: No, I tried it, it works as I described it. I just don't understand why.

Comment: @dialer I agree with you on *Why does casting a boxed enum type to an int? fail, but casting a boxed int to an int? succeeds, and a non-boxed enum type to and int?*, its confusing. But I disagree passing my original `enum[]` to your `MyCast<TIn, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TIn> e)` makes it successful. Are you sure, calling `enum[].MyCast<enum, int>().MyCast<int, int?>()` works without exception provided the internal implementation is the same? Na, I dont think so, which is what the linked question is about.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying, and this is the difference that happens: As you know, `(My)CastIterator` would only get called once because of the `return enumerable` in the other function. But at this point, the non-`My` variant has an `IEnumerable` which contains `object`s, which box `Gender`s, whereas the `My`-variant has an `IEnumerable<int>` which contains ***int***s (eventually boxed by the `(object)`, but still `int`s in the end). Casting `object` to `int?` is an invalid cast, but casting `int` to and `int?` is successful. Nevertheless, that entire thing is really strange.

Comment: @dialer appreciate the code, though for some reason I can't open it here. But I understood what you're talking about. Indeed it works that way. I missed the "non-boxing" part of your comment.

Comment: Apparently, this seems to be the reason for that behavior: (1) You *can* cast a boxed enum to an `int`. (2) You *can* cast a boxed `int` to an `int?`. (3) You *can* cast a *NON-boxed* enum to an `int?`. (4) You can *NOT* cast a boxed enum to an `int?`.

Comment: @dialer Oh yes cool find. Its worth making it an answer here! **Following casts are valid in both boxed and non-boxed contests:**
`T to T`, `T to T?`, `T? to T`, `enum to int`, `int to enum`, `int? to enum`, `enum? to int`. 

The last two are really confusing. If C# had not let that, it was easy remembering. **The following casts are valid only when non-boxed:**
`enum to int?`, `int to enum?`, `enum? to int?`, `int? to enum?`

Of course assuming `int` is the underlying type of the `enum`. I think I should make it my mantra to remember those :)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to deferred execution. The latter statement actually tries to cast `Gender.Male` to `int?`. In contrast, the first statement actually performs the cast operation to an `int` and gets a `List<int>` before deferring the execution to cast those to `int?`; clearly `int` to `int?` has an implicity conversion defined already.

Comment: I dont think that's the case at all.