# enum[] is IEnumerable<int> returns true in a generic method

Tags: c#, generics, enums, typechecking

This is a followup to this question: [Cast<int>.Cast<int?> applied on generic enum collection results in invalid cast exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292623/castint-castint-applied-on-generic-enum-collection-results-in-invalid-cast)

```
enum Gender { Male, Female }

Gender g = Gender.Male;

bool b = g is int; // false, alright no issues
b = new[] { g } is IEnumerable<int>; // false, alright no issues
b = Is<Gender, int>(g); //false, alright no issues
b = Is<Gender[], IEnumerable<int>>(new[] { g }); // true, why on earth !!!

static bool Is<S, T>(S s)
{
    return s is T;
}
```

Why is that `Gender[] is IEnumerable<int>` returns `true` in the generic case? Especially when they are not type compatible?

```
IEnumerable<int> c = new[] { Gender.Male }; //not compilable
```

It had tripped me in the question I linked! I think this question is the crux of the issue of the linked question.

---

For someone interested, this is a corner case with arrays (not really enums). Follow [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/) article in the answer to know more of this edge case. This doesn't happen with `List<T>` for instance:

```
b = Is<List<Gender>, IEnumerable<int>>(new List<Gender> { g }); // false, rightly
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is one of those cases where the C# definition of `is` differs from the CLI's definition of `isinst`, which evidently treats enums as their underlying base type when checking for array assignment compatibility. (Eric Lippert wrote a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/24/why-is-covariance-of-value-typed-arrays-inconsistent.aspx) that explains why `uint[]` is treated as an `int[]` by the CLI but not by C#; I suspect the same explanation applies here.) You don't even need generics to demonstrate:

```
Gender g = Gender.Male;
Console.WriteLine(new[] { g } is IEnumerable<int>); // False
Console.WriteLine((object)new[] { g } is IEnumerable<int>); // True
```

The first `is` expression is optimized to `false` at *compile time* because the C# compiler "knows" `Gender[]` isn't an `IEnumerable<int>`. The second `is` expression generates an `isinst` instruction which is evaluated at *run time*. Quoting Eric Lippert:

> It is unfortunate that C# and the CLI specifications disagree on this minor point but we are willing to live with the inconsistency.

Comment: Here is Eric's post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/24/why-is-covariance-of-value-typed-arrays-inconsistent.aspx

Comment: @vcsjones: Thanks! I was trying to find it.

Comment: @MichaelLiu, thanks, excellent find. Haa the weird arrays!! :x